# Elastic Search. Dynamic scoring based on doc field

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I am using elasticsearch 6.4 and I was trying to find any workable solution for my problem.  So my problem is I have doc and I am trying to score depending on id from query. Simplified doc structure is look like:

```
{
    "rates": [
     { "id": 1, "score_rate": 4.0},
     { "id": 2, "score_rate": 5.0}, 
     { "id": 3, "score_rate": 0.0}
   ]
}
```

The rates field is nested.

1. At my first attempt I tied to achieve this goal based on the query script_score function:

   ```
   {"script_score":{"script":{"params":{"id":1,"min":0.0},"id":"secondary_rate"}}}
   ```

Where secondary_rate is script in painless

```
double min_threshold = (double) params.min;
double score = min_threshold;

for (int i = 0; i < params._source.rates.length; ++i){
     def rate = params._source.rates[i];
     if (rate.id == params.id){
        c_score = category.score_rate;
        break;
}
}
return c_score;
```

But this doesn't work because nested field can't accessed in script throughout `doc['rates']` and `_source` field is not available anymore (https://discuss.elastic.co/t/painless-null-pointer-exception/128245) in script_functions.

2. In second attempt I tried to use combination of NestedQuery and FieldValueFactor
   something that look like: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/nested-value-on-function-score/29935/2. But unfortunately NestedQuery make second query and join (I can't control how joined  is performed) results of it with root query, and if root query is empty  Result of NestedQuery just added to root results. This behavior is unacceptable for my business logic.
3. On third attempt I tried to reindex rates field as array and encoded info about id in it. So field from example above will look like:
   `{ "rates": [0, 4.0, 5.0, 0.0]}`

   Again I used script function, but there is no guarantee for order of elements (from official Elastic Search docs array considered as "bag of values" ). To have elements in the 
   same order as in index time I need to use `_source` field (that is not available in 6.4).

So I am kind of stuck on this problem and have no ideas how to solve it. So any suggestions or hints are very welcome. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how to make it work properly please write it in a comments. 
But for know I create workaround:

Because array of rates has relatively small size. I managed to created Float field for each value dynamically, and then in search time I pass name of those fields as parameter to my script_score (parameter rates_keys) and just sum the values. So function in painless look like:

```
double add_score = 0.0;
String key;
for (int i = 0; i != params.rates_keys.length; ++i){
    rate_key = params.rates_keys[i];
    if(!doc[rate_key].empty) add_score += doc[rate_key].value;
}
return add_score;
```